# Spring + Jackson - @JsonView not returning Objects

Tags: json, spring, spring-mvc, jackson

I have a Spring boot project with Jackson.

I have this controller annotated with `@JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)`

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/reservations")
@JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
public ResponseEntity<Iterable<Reservation>> getReservationList() {
        User user = authenticationfacade.getAuthenticatedUser();
        Iterable<Reservation> reservations = service.findAllByUserAndByOrderByFromDateDesc(user);

        return new ResponseEntity<Iterable<Reservation>>(reservations, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

My reservation Object is

```
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private Long reservationId;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "userId")
    @JsonBackReference(value="reservations-user-reference")
    private User user;

    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name="plateId")
    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    @JsonBackReference(value="reservations-plate-reference")
    private Plate plate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private Date fromDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @DateTimeFormat(pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private Date toDate;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    @JsonSerialize(using = CustomDateTimeSerializer.class)
    private Date requestDate;

    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private int price;

    @JsonBackReference(value="reservations-park-reference")
    @ManyToOne(cascade= CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "parkId")
    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private Park park;

    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private String status;
```

When sending the request, i'm just getting all the fields I annotated except `Park` and `Plate`...

```
[
  {
    "reservationId": 111,
    "fromDate": "08-06-2017 16:30:00",
    "toDate": "09-06-2017 16:30:00",
    "price": 0,
    "status": "Active"
  },
  {
    "reservationId": 220,
    "fromDate": "09-05-2017 10:45:00",
    "toDate": "16-05-2017 11:00:00",
    "price": 0,
    "status": "Active"
  },
```

This is Plate.class (Park class in analogue)

```
@Entity
public class Plate {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private Long plateId;

    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private String plateNumber;

    @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)
    private String plateName;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="userId")
    @JsonBackReference(value="plates-user-reference")
    private User user;

    private boolean favourite;

    @JsonIgnore
    private boolean enabled;
```

This is the View Class

```
public class Views {


    public static class UserView{

    }

    public static class MobileAppView{

    }
}
```

I tried to annotate with @JsonView also Park and Plate fields, with no luck...

Comment: Please paste the code of Park and Plate classes also. Have you used @JsonView in them ?

Comment: Added Plate class, i've tried both, with no luck...

Comment: Ok thanks. Please replace @JsonView(Views.MobileApp.class) with @JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class) in class Plate i.e. same class name as you have given in reservation object. Try once

Comment: Sorry, it was a typo, they are annotated correctly with `@JsonView(Views.MobileAppView.class)` i edited the post

Comment: You have used JsonBackReference with Park, Plate & both are not coming. As per the definition of @JsonBackReference, the property annotated with this annotation is not serialized.

Comment: Oh... thanks... did not ever thought to JsonBackReference